# Sigil of Force + of the Night, and dual-wielding

Tags: guild-wars-2

Will a [Sigil of Force](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Sigil_of_Force) + [Sigil of the Night](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Sigil_of_the_Night) give +15% at night when dual-wielding?

And does it matter which weapon the sigil is on? For example, I have [Superior Accuracy](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Superior_Sigil_of_Accuracy) on my main hand and [Superior Force](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Superior_Sigil_of_Force) on my offhand -- does this mean only my offhand is getting +5% damage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will give a 15% damage bonus at night with 2 weapons, no off hand doesn't matter which sigil is where as long as it is equipped

You can test this by using a sigil of bloodlust or perception and see that it gives you stacks no matter what.